# Evaluating R code in YAML header

Tags: r, yaml, metadata, knitr, r-markdown

Consider the following Rmd file,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "baptiste"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
test: "`r paste('_metadata.yaml')`"
---

```{r}
cat(rmarkdown::metadata$test)
```
````

[image]

The date is processed (knitted) by R before being passed to pandoc for conversion to md and html. The custom field `test`, however, is unevaluated.

What's the difference? Can one force knitr/rmarkdown to evaluate an arbitrary field in the yaml header?

Note: the actual purpose is not to just `print()` a filename as in this dummy example, but to load an external yaml file containing metadata (author information), process it with R, and output a string that will be injected in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does evaluate the code.  If you run foo.Rmd with

```
rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", clean = FALSE)
```

you'll see an intermediate file (the pandoc input) called `foo.knit.md` left behind.  It will look like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "baptiste"
date: "2017-08-12"
output: html_document
test: "_metadata.yaml"
---


```r
cat(rmarkdown::metadata$test)
```

```
## `r paste('_metadata.yaml')`
```
````

I don't know how to see that from within the document (your example shows that `metadata$test` doesn't work), but there's probably some trick or other to get at it.

Comment: thanks, I should have checked the md output rather than relying on this little-documented `rmarkdown::metadata`

Answer (score 4):

The standard metadata field `data` and your custom field `test` are not actually treated any differently. This code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "baptiste"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes
test: "`r paste('_metadata.yaml')`"
---

```{r}
cat(rmarkdown::metadata$date)
cat(rmarkdown::metadata$test)
```
````

leads to the following output:

[image]

As you can see, also `date` was not evaluated. I have not found any functionality in the `rmarkdown` or `knitr` packages. But the following simple function does the trick at least for your simple example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "baptiste"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes
test: "`r paste('_metadata.yaml')`"
---

```{r}
eval_meta <- function(x) eval(parse(text = gsub("`|r", "", x)))
eval_meta(rmarkdown::metadata$date)
eval_meta(rmarkdown::metadata$test)
```
````

[image]

Whether that works in your more complex situation is another question, however.

Comment: good point, thanks! I didn't think of checking that, the logic's a bit puzzling to me.

Comment: great answer. however, regex pattern could've been better with `"(^\`r\\s+)|(\`$)" `. otherwise, `r` letter(s) in the call are being swallowed e.g. `fo mat()`.